# MSSQL Recovery Model Setup with Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server

Setup:
Two MSSQL 2014 servers, one publisher/distributor and the other subscriber.  Both are currently set to full recovery.

The database size is relatively small (100g), but we generate about 30g of logs every day.  My goal is to have a setup where I can perform backups without downtime.

A full backup on the this database takes about an hour in which it is effectively unavailable and impacts our user base.

The replicated database is taking a log backup every hour and a full backup every day.

Questions
Is it possible and/or advised to have a Simple recovery model on the primary database (in order to prevent the need to do log and full backups), while maintaining a Full recovery model on the replicated database?

Comment: Replication is not dependent on the recovery model, it is possible.  I'd suggest you read http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-is-replication-recovery-model-dependent/

Comment: Backups should not affect user operations on the DB restore will lock the table but a backup should not need a table lock.